# CAKeyAnimation with CATransform3D

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I would like to animate a view along a path. While it moves from the start to end of the path I also want it to scale up. To start I apply a scale transform to the view (.1 scale). The moving along the path works great but I am having problems applying the scale-to-normal transform during the animation.

```
        PointF p0 = pt;
        PointF p3 = FormCenter;

        CGPath path = new CGPath();
        path.MoveToPoint(p0);
        path.AddQuadCurveToPoint(p3.X, p0.Y, p3.X, p3.Y);

        CAKeyFrameAnimation a = new CAKeyFrameAnimation();
        a.KeyPath = "position";
        a.Path = path;
        a.Values = new NSObject[1] {NSValue.FromCATransform3D(CATransform3D.Identity)};
        a.Duration = 3;
        nav.View.Layer.AddAnimation(a, a.KeyPath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a group animation to animate multiple properties

In this case, assuming you have created two animations, one for animating the alpha, and one for animating the zie, this is how you create it:

```
var group = CAAnimationGroup.CreateAnimation ();
group.Animations = new CAAnimation [] { alpha, size };
group.Duration = delay; 
layer.AddAnimation (group, "showup");
```